# Error while running SQL query, window functions

Tags: sql, mysql, window-functions

I am trying to find the YoY growth of the users and trying to write a mysql query using window functions.

Below is my query to find the lag :

```
select substr(create_time, 1, 4) as date,
       count(*) as count,
       lag(count(*), 1) over substr(create_time, 1, 4)
from test_table
group by 1
order by 1
```

Note: `create_time` column looks like: `2019-03-29 20:12:03`, so I'm using the `substr` to get the year.

Error:

> [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'substr(create_time, 1, 4)
> from test_table
> group by 1
> order by 1' at line 3  [Script position: 398 - 453]

I am debugging it for the past 2 hours, what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

The expected result should be a response with a column lag.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding braces and PARTITION BY or ORDER BY:

```
lag(count(*), 1) over (ORDER BY substr(create_time, 1, 4))
```

```
WITH X AS
(
  select substr(create_time, 1, 4) as date,
         count(*) as countX
  from test_table
  group by 1
)
Select 
      Date,
      lag(countX, 1) over (ORDER BY date)
From X
order by 1
```

Comment: Same error :( : [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY substr(create_time, 1, 4))
from test_table
group by date
order b' at line 3  [Script position: 398 - 464]

Comment: How about via the CTE example?

Comment: It was the issue using mysql old version